# Formatting a table to look nice

Tags: list-manipulation, formatting

my current code is:

```
binsize = 21;
data = {535, 481, 554, 567, 565, 513, 526, 506, 565, 475, 552, 533, 
   474, 556, 520, 508, 597, 479, 537, 499, 546, 473, 579, 526, 594, 
   477, 518, 538, 497, 565};
firstbin = 472;
a = BinCounts[data, {firstbin, Max[data] + binsize, binsize}];
b = Range[firstbin, Max[data] + binsize, binsize];
Transpose[{Take[b, Length[a]], a}] // TableForm
```

Which does give me a nice table, however I would like the bins to be labeled something like "472-492    6" instead of just "472   6"

any advice would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`HistogramList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HistogramList.html) to get bin limits and bin counts in one step and process the output to get the desired structure:

```
{binlims, bincounts} = HistogramList[data, {firstbin, Max[data] + binsize, binsize}];
bins = Row[{#, #2 - 1}, "-"] & @@@ Partition[binlims, 2, 1];
TableForm[Transpose[{bins, bincounts}]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `MovingMap`, `` Developer`PartitionMap `` or 
the (undocumented) 6-argument form of `Partition` to get the first column:

```
bins2 = MovingMap[Row[{First@#, Last@# - 1}, "-"] &, binlims, 1]
bins3 = Developer`PartitionMap[Row[{First@#, Last@# - 1}, "-"] &, binlims, 2, 1];
bins4 = Partition[binlims, 2, 1, {1, -1}, {}, Row[{#, #2 - 1}, "-"] &];
bins == bins2 == bins3 == bins4
```

> True

Finally, you can also use a combination of `StringRiffle` and `ToString` in place of `Row`as follows:

```
bins5 = Partition[binlims, 2, 1, {1, -1}, {}, StringRiffle[ToString/@{#, #2 - 1}, " - "]&]
TableForm[Transpose[{bins5, bincounts}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Wombles, you are welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way:

```
bb = b - 1;
c = Complement[bb, {Min[bb]}];
Transpose[{Take[b, Length[a]], ConstantArray["---", Length[a]], c, a}] // TableForm
```

Here is the output:

[image]

With MarcoB's hint, and some experimenting:

```
c = Complement[b - 1, {Min[b - 1]}];
y = Map[ToString, Take[b, Length[a]]];
z = Map[ToString, c]; 
Transpose@{Map[StringJoin, Transpose[{y, ConstantArray["---", Length[a]], z}]], a} // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: I wish I knew more about string manipulation to get the first three columns to combine to one column of text!

Comment: You might want `ToString` and `StringJoin`

Comment: @MarcoB, Yes, Thank you!  That's what I was looking for!  I actually found `ToString` and figured there was a way of joining the columns ...  Probably there is a more efficient way then what I've put together.  At least it is a start.

Comment: `Row` as suggested in kglr's answer, can also work as a substitute for `StringJoin`.